# Error when trying to loop through entities from an Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

i keep getting this error, "The current value 'String.Empty' type is not compatible with the expected 'System.Boolean' type", when i try to loop through a bunch of entities from an Azure table, i am only new to using Azure so this could be something very easy, the error that i am getting.

my code :

```
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the table client
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Get the data service context
        TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

        // Create a new customer entity
        user = new UserDetailsEntity();

        //Setting the fields of the new userEntity
        user.username = usernameText.Text;
        user.password = passwordText.Text;
        user.subscriptionID = subText.Text;
        user.subscriptionName = subscriptionNameText.Text;
        user.thumbprint = thumbprintText.Text;
        user.email = emailText.Text;
        user.phoneNumber = "3530" + numberText.Text;


        int rowCount = 1;


        CloudTableQuery<UserDetailsEntity> Query = (from en in serviceContext.CreateQuery<UserDetailsEntity>("userdetails")
                                                             select   en).AsTableServiceQuery<UserDetailsEntity>();

        //error occurs in the next line
        foreach (UserDetailsEntity ent in Query)
        {

            rowCount++;
        }

        user.RowKey = rowCount.ToString();





            // Add the new customer to the people table
            serviceContext.AddObject("userdetails", user);

            // Submit the operation to the table service
            serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();
            //Set the variables so they can be retrieved when the next screen loads
            Application.Current.Properties["username"] = usernameText.Text;
            Application.Current.Properties["password"] = passwordText.Text;

            Window1 userHome = new Window1();
            this.Close(); //to close Password window 
            userHome.Show(); //to show Main form 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more code, I cannot tell you exactly where the problem is, however the exception is fairly explanatory. You are trying to set a boolean property to a value of a string.

If the error is occurring in your foreach as you noted in the code comment, then I would check how your `UserDetailsEntity` object is set up. There is probably a property that is set up as a boolean, yet your data is coming back as a String.Empty. The reason you are getting this in your foreach is because your LINQ query is of type IQueryable, so it will not actually execute  and fill your objects until you actually access the data (by your foreach)*. So, you could put breakpoints in your UserDetailsEntity properties to see which one it is if this is not blatent from looking at the code.

*Keep in mind that this is the N+1 problem, where you are making a call to the database on each iteration of your loop. You can resolve this by calling .ToList() to eager load all of your data at once into your query...if this is a problem for you, that is.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, the error is occuring on the line 

foreach (UserDetailsEntity ent in Query)

Which is why i am confused as to why the error is occuring

Comment: @StevenR Sorry, I missed that, I have updated my answer to help you figure this out better

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll definetly do what you suggested